Turbidity Data wont Send in Firebase realtime database
I am creating a water monitoring system. I want to monitor the PH, Temperate and Turbidity in it. My problem is My Turbidity Data wont send in my firebase realtime database. My Turbidity wont give a data If I want to send the data in the database. But If I remove the firebase code, it works properly.
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#include "DFRobot_ESP_PH.h"
#include "EEPROM.h"
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <Firebase_ESP_Client.h>

#define WIFI_SSID "ESP_32"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "12345678"

#define API_KEY "****"

#define DATABASE_URL "****" 

#define USER_EMAIL "****"
#define USER_PASSWORD "****"

// Define Firebase Data object
FirebaseData fbdo;

FirebaseAuth auth;
FirebaseConfig config;

DFRobot_ESP_PH ph;
#define ESPADC 4096.0   //the esp Analog Digital Convertion value
#define ESPVOLTAGE 3300 //the esp voltage supply value
#define PH_PIN 35  
float phvoltage, phValue, temperature = 25;

#define SENSOR_PIN  19

OneWire oneWire(SENSOR_PIN);
DallasTemperature DS18B20(&oneWire);

float tempC; // temperature in Celsius
float tempF; // temperature in Fahrenheit
float tVoltage;
float turbidityValue;

#define BUTTON_PIN 15
#define LED_PIN 17
#define TURBIDITY_PIN 13

bool buttonState = false;

#include <ThreeWire.h>  
#include <RtcDS1302.h>

ThreeWire myWire(27,25,12); // IO, SCLK, CE
RtcDS1302<ThreeWire> Rtc(myWire);

/* SENSORS USED */
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  DS18B20.begin();
  EEPROM.begin(32);
  ph.begin();
  Rtc.Begin();
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  Serial.print("Connecting to Wi-Fi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
  {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(300);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connected with IP: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Serial.println();

  /* Assign the api key (required) */
  config.api_key = API_KEY;

  /* Assign the user sign-in credentials */
  auth.user.email = USER_EMAIL;
  auth.user.password = USER_PASSWORD;

  /* Assign the RTDB URL (required) */
  config.database_url = DATABASE_URL;

  // Comment or pass false value when WiFi reconnection will control by your code or third party library e.g. WiFiManager
  Firebase.reconnectNetwork(true);
 read timeout can be occurred.
  fbdo.setBSSLBufferSize(4096 /* Rx buffer size in bytes from 512 - 16384 */, 1024 /* Tx buffer size in bytes from 512 - 16384 */);

  // Limit the size of response payload to be collected in FirebaseData
  fbdo.setResponseSize(2048);

  Firebase.begin(&config, &auth);

  Firebase.setDoubleDigits(5);

  config.timeout.serverResponse = 10 * 1000;

  // Setup button and LED pins
  pinMode(BUTTON_PIN, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
  // Read button state
  bool newButtonState = digitalRead(BUTTON_PIN);
  
  // Check if button state has changed
  if (newButtonState != buttonState) {
    delay(50); // Debounce
    if (newButtonState == LOW) { // Button is pressed
      sendDataToFirebase();
    }
  }
  buttonState = newButtonState;

  // Blink LED if data is being sent
  if (Firebase.ready() && newButtonState == LOW) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, !digitalRead(LED_PIN)); // Toggle LED
    delay(500); // Blink interval
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // Turn off LED
  }

  delay(100); // Adjust delay as needed
}

void sendDataToFirebase() {

  tVoltage = analogRead(TURBIDITY_PIN);
  turbidityValue = tVoltage * (5.0 / 1024.0);
  
  DS18B20.requestTemperatures();       // send the command to get temperatures
  tempC = DS18B20.getTempCByIndex(0);  // read temperature in °C
  tempF = tempC * 9 / 5 + 32; // convert °C to °F 
  
  phvoltage = analogRead(PH_PIN) / ESPADC * ESPVOLTAGE;
  phValue = ph.readPH(phvoltage, temperature);

  RtcDateTime now = Rtc.GetDateTime();
  char dateTimeString[20];
  printDateTime(now, dateTimeString); // Get date and time string

  // Print sensor data to serial monitor for debugging
  Serial.print("Temperature (C): ");
  Serial.println(tempC);
  Serial.print("PH Value: ");
  Serial.println(phValue);
  Serial.print("Turbidity: ");
  Serial.println(turbidityValue);

  // Firebase.ready() should be called repeatedly to handle authentication tasks.
  if (Firebase.ready())
  {
    String firebasePath = "/SensorData/" + String(dateTimeString) + "/";

    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, firebasePath + "Temperature", tempC);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, firebasePath + "PH Value", phValue);
    Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, firebasePath + "Turbidity", turbidityValue);
   
  }
  delay(2000); // Delay for 2 seconds after sending data
}

#define countof(a) (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]))

void printDateTime(const RtcDateTime& dt, char* dateString)
{
    snprintf_P(dateString, 
            20,
            PSTR("%02u-%02u-%04u %02u:%02u:%02u"),
            dt.Day(),
            dt.Month(),
            dt.Year(),
            dt.Hour(),
            dt.Minute(),
            dt.Second() );
}

 In this part of the code I Get all the sensors data analyze it and send it to the firebase database I've search on internet how to fix it. But I havent found any. I hope someone will help me fix it. 



It may be due to type of the Turbidity value. Check this line:
Firebase.RTDB.setFloat(&fbdo, firebasePath + "Turbidity", turbidityValue);

Type exception will prevent Firebase to record it if type mismatch happens. Check the actual value inside that loop and check field type definition on Firebase side. Only reasonable explanation may be this.

Then Why In this code
Serial.print("Turbidity: ");
Serial.println(turbidityValue);
It still give 0 output.

You have also this part which only triggered when attempting to write to Firebase. It either causes type exception or reset value:  turbidityValue = tVoltage * (5.0 / 1024.0); Print the values before and after this part to see what is really happening there.
